# unable to receive json to servlet post method

Tags: json, servlets, jquery-ajaxq

I was trying to send `json` data to my serlvlet. But when I try to receive that I got `null`. Below is my code. Where am I wrong? I don't understand.

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function test(){
    var dataa={
             "otp":"abc",
             "email":"abcabc"
        };
    $.ajax({ 
       url: "AbcTest",
       type: 'POST',
       dataType: 'json',
       data:
       {    dataa: JSON.stringify(dataa)
          },
       contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       success: function (response) {
           console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
       },
       error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
          alert("error");
          console.log(xhr, resp, text);
       } 
  });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="test();">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**AbcTest Servlet**

```
package org.abc.ussd;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
@WebServlet("/AbcTest")
public class AbcTest extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public AbcTest() {
        super();
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("dataa"));
    }
}
```

I am getting null in `dataa` in `servlet`. How can I receive json data from jsp page to this servlet.

Comment: Did you try debugging (the front-end via browser debugger, network monitor, the back-end via IDE debugger) to narrow down the problem? If not, please do and share the conclusions.

Comment: well, in browser I got no error in developer tools console in chrome. and in servlet I am getting null printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue when I change the content type to

```
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;",
```

**I got below output in console**

[image]